# How to find the Highest IP of given Two

Tags: tcl

Can anyone tell me how to find the Highest IP address from show output which has two IP address values. Please help .
 i tried the below, is any other better option.

```
set ip1 "10.2.244.255"
set ip2 "10.2.33.224" 
set ip1 [split $ip1 .] 
set ip2 [split $ip2 .] 
foreach i $ip1 j $ip2 {  
    if { $i > $j} {
         puts "ip1 is greater" break 
    } elseif { $i < $j } {
         puts "ip2 is greater" break 
    } elseif { $i == $j } {
         continue 
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post what you have tried, and the incorrect results?

Comment: set ip1 "10.2.244.255"
set ip2 "10.2.33.224"

set ip1 [split $ip1 .]
set ip2 [split $ip2 .]

foreach i $ip1 j $ip2 {
    if { $i > $j} {
        puts "ip1 is greater"
        break
    } elseif { $i < $j } {
        puts "ip2 is greater"
        break
    } elseif { $i == $j } {
        continue
    }
}  .

Comment: please add the code to your original question, so other users don't have to dig into comments to look for it.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use the `-dictionary` option of `[lsort]` which does the right thing with numbers in strings:

```
lsort -dictionary {10.2.244.255 10.2.33.224}
```

sorts the ip addresses from smallest to largest. So the result is the last number in the list.

You can encapsulate this in a function:

```
proc larger_ip {a b} {
    return [lindex [lsort -dictionary [list $a $b]] end]
}
```

Comment: in fact, this can be generalized to multiple ip addresses: `proc largest_ip {args} {...}`

Answer (score 0):

IP addresses are just a human memorable representation of a 32 bit value. The [tcllib ip package](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/dns/tcllib_ip.html) has commands to manipulate these and in this case I think `ip::toInteger` would be most useful.

```
proc compareIp {addr1 addr2} {
    expr {[ip::toInteger $addr2] - [ip::toInteger $addr1]}
}
```

should give the usual negative, 0, positive result for less-than, equal to or greater than comparisons. This package will also handle masked addresses (ie: 10.0.1.0/16) for network or address sets.